# If $x$ and $y$ are positive numbers less than $20$ for which $x+y+xy=76$, what is $x+y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

What is a simple way to solve this problem? I can do it by trying $x$ and $y$, starting from $1$. That does not look like the best way.

> If $x$ and $y$ are positive numbers less than $20$ for which $x+y+xy=76$, what is $x+y$?

Comment: Please check tag definitions before applying tags which have nothing to do with your question.  This has nothing to do with factorials.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

\begin{align}xy+x+y&=76\\
x(y+1)+y&=76\\
x(y+1)+y+1&=77\\
(x+1)(y+1)&=77
\end{align}

As $1,7,11,77$ are the only positive divisors of $77$, $(x,y)$ should be $(6,10)$ or $(10,6)$. Thus, $x+y=16$

Answer (score 6):

**hint:**$x+y+xy=76\implies x+y+xy+1=77\implies (x+1)(y+1)=77$